# Stop Python script outside of the terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I have made a python script based on the `pyautogui` module, which controls my mouse and keyboard and can automate some tasks I have at work.

However, sometimes, it doesn't really go as planned and I have to stop the script (even though it might be in the middle of something). The problem is that the terminal window is not in front anymore, so I cannot press ctrl+c.

I have heard that it is possible to use ctrl+break as well, but it does not seem to work (might be because I have to run the script inside of a remote desktop connection). And the failsafe on `pyautogui` is to drag the mouse to the top left corner, but it does not seem to work in a remote desktop connection as well.

Is there some way I can add my own failsafe, or some keyboard combination I can try to stop the ongoing python script, even though the terminal is not accessible?

Comment: just kill he process in Task manager

Comment: Using ctrl + alt + delete will just access the task manager in my main system, not in the remote connection

Comment: Well if you don't have access to the remote desktop, I don't see how you expect being able to stop the script...

Comment: I have access to the remote desktop, but when I use it, and try to use ctrl+alt+delete, It registers for the task manager on my main system.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're on *nix-like system: just run `pkill python` in a new terminal to kill all python processes of your user.
You can run:
`ps ax` to find the exact process you want to kill then
`kill -9 <the PID of your process>`

To start a new tty you can press ctrl + F4 then log in

If you're on windows: ctrl+alt+del to the task manager then seek your python process and kill it

Answer (score 1):

On Windows systems, try ctrl+alt+end. This will open the task manager on the computer you are Remote Desktop'd into.